# QuickLook - Application UTI overriding QLGenerator UTI

Tags: plist, quicklook, uti

I wrote a .qlgenerator for a particular set of file types and defined a supposedly correct set of "Imported Type UTIs" in the .plist file.

The form of UTIs is "public.archive.xxx.yyy", where "xxx" is a vendor code and "yyy" is a particular file type.

I write "supposedly", because everything seems to work fine until I install the .qlgenerator on another computer running 10.5. There it just doesn't work. Using qlmanage command I found out that the generator plugin gets properly registered for the given UTIs but when I invoke it to show preview of a file it says that my files are of type "public.archive.yyy" "rather than "public.archive.xxx.yyy". I eventually found the reason for that: On that second computer, there is an application installed, which defines those UTIs and registers itself as "Editor". The application does not provide QuickLook plugin but renders mine unusable anyway.

How can I make sure that my plugin will be used, even if someone has this (or similar) application installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Six years later (2019), this question is still relevant and yet, Quicklook is still dramatically underdocumented. One wonders whether Apple really want developers to support their platform...

Comment: I still don't have correct answer and still don't know how to programmatically set the QL preview window size..